# Echo Server Client using UDP Sockets in C

Tags: c, networking, udp, client, echo

The following program has the motive of sending a data gram from client to the server and the data gram being echoed back to the client as an acknowledgment.

I have tried to terminate the program when an empty string is
 accepted from the server side.
 I executed the program in Fedora 14. 
 The error I encounter is that there is an "Error in SendTo"- Socket on
 Non-Socket.

I am unable to figure out the mistake. Please do point out the mistake. Suggestions are welcome.

I have tried reading other resources regarding this, but have not been able to get a hold out of it.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Server:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<sys/types.h> 
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<sys/socket.h> 
#include<string.h> 
#include<unistd.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
#define PORT 7844

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    char buf[2000];
    int sockfd,len,a;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
    if((sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0))<0)
    {
        printf("Error creating socket\n"); 
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("UDP Server Socket Created Successfully.\n"); 
    bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port=htons(PORT); 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
    if(bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr))<0)
    {
        perror("Error binding socket."); 
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("UDP Server Socket Binded.\n"); 
    len=sizeof(cliaddr);
    do {
        strcpy(buf," "); 
        if((a=recvfrom(sockfd,buf,sizeof(buf),0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&len))<0){
            perror("ERROR"); 
            exit(0);
        }
        printf("From Client : %s",buf); 
        if((sendto(sockfd,buf,a,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,len))<0)
        {
            perror("NOTHING SENT"); 
            exit(0);
        }
        printf("Server : ");
        fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
        if((sendto(sockfd,buf,a,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,len))<0)
        {
            perror("NOTHING SENT"); 
            exit(0);
        }
    } while(strcmp(buf," ")!=0); 
    close(sockfd); 
    return 0;
}
```

CLIENT

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h> 
#include<netinet/in.h> 
#include<sys/socket.h> 
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<string.h> 
#include<unistd.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
#define PORT 7844

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    int sockfd,len;
    struct sockaddr_in serv,cliaddr;
    char buff[2000]; 
    if((sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0))<0)
    {
        perror("ERROR creating socket");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("UDP Client Socket Created Successfully.\n"); 
    memset(&serv,0,sizeof(serv)); 
    serv.sin_family=AF_INET; 
    serv.sin_port=htons(PORT);
    serv.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]);
    do
    {
        printf("Client : ");
        fgets(buff,sizeof(buff),stdin);
        if((sendto(sockfd,buff,sizeof(buff),0,(struct sockaddr *)&serv,sizeof(serv)))<0) {
            perror("ERROR IN SENDTO");
        }
        if(strcmp(buff," ")==0) {
            exit(0);
        } 
        strcpy(buff," ");
        if((recvfrom(sockfd,buff,sizeof(buff),0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&len))<0) {
            perror("ERROR IN RECVFROM"); 
            exit(0);
        }
        fputs("From Server : ",stdout); 
        fputs(buff,stdout); 

    } while(strcmp(buff," ")!=0);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Please let me know if I can terminate a program using empty string. 
Also let me know of flaws in the program.
Thank you, once again.

Comment: Sometimes less whitespace is better.

Comment: Why does your server code call `socket` twice?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Duh, because he forgot to check the return status the first time!

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Oh! Error in copying. Copied from the backup copy. :P

Answer (score 1):

You are using `fgets`

From `man fgets`

`fgets()` reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops  after
       an  EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.

So when you enter a space and press return, you will get `" \n"` not the `" "` you are testing for.

Comment: Thank you @parkydr. Is there any other way I can terminate the program without string comparison?

Comment: You could use a signal, but the client would have to know the server PID.  Having a special message like you have is probably to best way.  Just test for " \n".

Comment: Thank you for your help. May I ask how the former can be performed?

Comment: It will only work if the client and server are on the same machine.  You call `kill` with the process id and signal id.  I still think the network message is better, you can then stop the process from anywhere.